# I need help creating a modding system in a Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to create a basic system that will allow only specific users to see and use modding links like "Delete" and "Edit".
I can't seem to find anything about role management in Facebook applications, and using my own external SQL table or XML file is frustratingly stupid in my opinion, considering the fact I'm only trying to classify certain users as Admins without hard-coding their UID's into the system.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to be fair, that this needs more info on how the person is classified as an admin?

Do they need to be nominated? Added by another admin? what?

If it's something that would be determined automatically, then you have your answer already, If you want certain people to be admins, but don't want to hard code, create an interface that allows you to select a person, and add them to a database list that says "this person is an admin" - I don't believe that facebook has it's own internal system to say "this person is a moderator" ...

Another thought would be to create a group on Facebook, and only have the people in the group to be allowed to be a member of the group, then you can check using FQL or the API's Group.getMembers whether they're a member of the group, and if they are, let them be an admin in the app.